# How to speed up Trim Macro

Tags: excel, trim, vba

Part of my macro uses the Trim function.  It happens to be the slowest part of my macro and I'm looking to speed it up.  Does anyone have a suggestion for some code that would achieve the same ends, but faster?

```
Sub Trim()

For Each c In Sheets("Approved Closing Data Draw").UsedRange c.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(c.Value) Next c

For Each c In Sheets("Pipeline - Underwriting Data D").UsedRange c.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(c.Value) Next c

For Each c In Sheets("Modifications").UsedRange c.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(c.Value) Next c

For Each c In Sheets("Lead Data").UsedRange c.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(c.Value) Next c

Sheets("Approved Closing Data Draw").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks more like a Code Review question...http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The two mains things are to turn off calculations and screen updating.  There are a few other things you can try.  See the link below.

https://www.soa.org/News-and-Publications/Newsletters/Compact/2012/january/com-2012-iss42-roper.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This should be faster:

```
Sub DoSheets()
    TrimUsedRange Sheets("Approved Closing Data Draw")
    TrimUsedRange Sheets("Pipeline - Underwriting Data D")
    'etc
End Sub

Sub TrimUsedRange(sht As Worksheet)
    Dim d, r As Long, c As Long

    With sht.UsedRange
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            'handle empty sheets
            .Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(.Value)
        Else
            d = .Value
            For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
            For c = 1 To UBound(d, 2)
                d(r, c) = WorksheetFunction.Trim(d(r, c))
            Next c
            Next r
            .Value = d
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Using just `Trim()` might be faster than `WorksheetFunction.Trim()`